# Combine 2 categories in one Menu item

Tags: menus

I wanted to combine multiple categories in one Menu item

I checked this dicussion, someone said:

> You'd have to make a custom link for that.
>
> Make your URL http://www.example.com/?cat=(id-white),(id-rabbit)

Below is my link but can't show the correct categories. ID is correct.

http://example.com/?cat=(id-32),(id-33)

Comment: What do you mean by “combine”? Should it display posts that have one of these categories or posts that have both?

Answer (score 2):

You misunderstood the quote, the URL needs to be

```
http://example.com/?cat=32,33
```

I just tested it and it seems to work. However, the title was only one of the categories' name, there might be other problems with this solution.

Answer (score 0):

Use the URL like this, it will show the content of both categories:

```
http://example.com/?cat=id-32+id-33
```

Answer (score 0):

This will show the content of both categories:

```
/product-category/spring-summer+pumps/
```